# Is there a way to add margin-bottom only for safari browsers for mobile devices?

Tags: css

I have a chatbox and it is working fine for all devices in all browsers except safari.

There the input box doesn't show up.

I think if I give a margin-bottom ,then it might work for safari too.

But I only want to do it for safari not for other browsers and that too for max-width:480px.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. What's the CSS you're using to position the chatbox? If you're using `100vh` for example, there is a known issue due to the dynamically changing size of the iOS Safari viewport.

Comment: yes,I am using vh unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can used browser specific calls in your style sheet like this:

```
/* Safari 11+ */
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
{ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
    selector { 
        property:value; 
    }
}}

/* Safari 10.1 */
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){ 
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (not (stroke-color:transparent)) {
    selector { 
        property:value; 
    }
}}

/* Safari 6.1-10.0 (not 10.1) */
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){ 
@media {
    selector { 
        property:value;
    }
}}
```

Learn more about Browser-Specific CSS here:

https://dev.to/krantikr/browser-specific-css-for-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-safari-and-edge-394p#safari